# Using a self-signed certificate with a chrome packaged app

Tags: google-chrome-app

I'm developing a Chrome packaged app (not an extension), which connects to the server over secure WebSocket. The server's certificate is self-signed, and this cannot be changed.

The problem is that on the chrome packaged app, the connection attempt fails with an ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE error.

In the Chrome browser, there is a work-around: The browser opens a security warning page. If user chooses to continue to the website, it goes on to the remote page. However there is no such work-around in a packaged app. Instead, the connection attempt just fails.

Is there any way to code the Chrome packaged app to accept a self-signed certificate?

Answer (score 1):

Found a work-around - open a browser from inside the chrome app. 
This is done by using a webview HTML element (webview is the chrome app name for iframe).
Now the chrome app user can accept the security risks of using a self-signed certificate, just as the web app user does.